# Is it possible to use spquery in WCF for sharepoint

Tags: wcf, spquery

I created custom wcf that retrieve items from the list. Is it possible to use spquery within the wcf to filter the list items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your WCF is located under '_layouts' folder and configured correctly you have access to the SharePoint object model as in web parts, application pages, etc. So you can use `list.GetItems(spQuery)` method to filter items.

You can read more about WCF services and SharePoint [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521586.aspx). How to configure your service you can find in this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx).

Comment: I can access client objects but when i test with wcftestclient exception shows `Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.`

Comment: this exception does not give any helpful information that I can use to help you (

Comment: Thanks i overcome this exception(I didn't end <Eq> taq).Now another exception `<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr>` .I used multi value lookup for joining two lists.pls help

Comment: This info lesser than you provided before. Could you provide a code that trows exception. Also you can try to test your query in [U2U Caml Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) tool.

Comment: `SPQuery listQueries = new SPQuery();listQueries.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + username + "</Value></Eq></Where>";listQueries.Joins = "<Join Type='Left' ListAlias='countryListAlias'><Eq><FieldRef Name='Country' RefType='ID'/><FieldRef List='countryListAlias' Name='ID'/></Eq></Join>";listQueries.ProjectedFields = "<Field Name='Code' List='countryListAlias' Type='Lookup' ShowField='Code'/>";listQueries.ViewFields = "<FieldRef List='countryListAlias' Name='Code' />";listQueries .ViewFieldsOnly = true;`

Comment: The above is join query code.I am getting execption if the lookup is multivale if the lookup is not multivalue then working fine

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to display code in comment

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you (( I have never used Join in spquery before (

Comment: No. I know that it is possible, but I have not got this task before )